# What is use of negative Limit in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

When i was reading about limit method then i found a line that was

> A negative limit is similar to a positive limit but closes the cursor
>   after returning a single batch of results. As such, with a negative
>   limit, if the limited result set does not fit into a single batch, the
>   number of documents received will be less than the specified limit.

I can't understand this explanation. So can any one explain this with a suitable Example?

Answer (score 0):

If your query returns 100 elements before applying the limit operation, then you have 10 batches of data for your query ( if you do it via mongo shell). You can iterate through the data via **it** command until end ( 10 iterations).

If you add **limit(30)** to your query, you indicate that you want to get only 30 elements. Mongod will keep the connection from the mongo shell open until you have gone through all data.

However, if you set **limit(-30)**, your query result on server still has 30 elements, but mongod only returns the first 10 elements to the shell, and you cannot go through the rest with **it** command because the connection is closed.